# Java Test Harness For JSON (de)serialiation

Tags: json, unit-testing, junit

I am wondering if anybody knows of some standard JSON unit tests that are used out there.

I have a library that does some JSON serialization and deserialization to a specific data object, which I would like to verify is correct.  I have homespun several tests which all pass, but I am suspicious there are many corner cases I missed.

I assume that some library out there must have fairly thorough unit tests which I could modify.  Does anybody know of any such tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download python, so that you have the standard library source code. Their test code is in: Lib/json/tests

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Java test framework for JSON, try [JSONassert](http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org) with JUnit.  It's very lightweight to use.

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/qaware/majx library allows you to match the JSON representation of an object against a pattern, that is also written in JSON.

```
String actual  = <<serialize your Object as JSON>>;
String pattern = "{ \"greeting\" : \"Hello, World!\", \"id\" : \"...\" }";

Majx.assertJsonMatches(pattern, actual);
```

Using this lib might help you to make your own tests easier and more correct. The lib itself has a high test coverage you can look at for examples, e.g. [here](https://github.com/qaware/majx/blob/master/src/test/java/de/qaware/majx/DocsTests.java).

Answer (score 0):

Here is great ["Parsing JSON is a Minefield"](http://seriot.ch/parsing_json.php) article backed by [a comprehensive test suite for RFC 7159 compliant JSON parsers](https://github.com/nst/JSONTestSuite)